# To create a to do list web application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

How to create a todo list in angular js that stores the list of todos in thr form of file in computer system.?
I have tried this using http services: get and post. But i get error while doing so..
The list of todos are stored in the web storage but not in computer

Comment: Are you asking to save to a file on the computer or do you want to save them for view in browser later, like with cookies?

Comment: Yes i want to save them to a file on the computer

Comment: Can we limit to modern browsers or should all browsers be supported?

Comment: Browsers are not a problem.

Comment: Post what you have tried

Comment: First link from Google https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_todo_application.htm

Comment: Same what we used to do in get method. Frankly speaking i didn't understand how to use post method. So one of you help me with post method

Answer (score 1):

This will allow you to right click and save as JSON file.

You can then use said file on the computer or upload it to the same or another website:

```js
//Reference a tag
var link = document.getElementById("downloadLink");

//Dummy data todos
var todos = [{
  name: 1,
  text: "hello world"
},{
  name: 2,
  text: "hello world"
}];

//Create download link
link.setAttribute("href", 'data:text/json,' + JSON.stringify(todos))
```

```html
<a id="downloadLink" href="#nuthinYet" target="_blank" download="test.json">download</a>
```